# JFrame not showing up in JApplet until applet is resized

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Java applet, and I am trying to add a JFrame to it. I am calling:

```
add(new MyJFrameSubclass());
```

But when I launch the application, my `JFrame` isn't shown until I resize the window.

Comment: Are you creting an Applet to embed in a webpage?  Or are you trying to create a standalone application?

Comment: I am trying to create an application that functions as both - so you can run the jar locally, or use it as an applet.

Answer (score 2):

This may be too elementary of a suggestion, but sticking in a `validate()` or `repaint()` can sometimes solve problems that seem complicated.

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix is to add a `frame.show();` after you add your JFrame, I had the same issue and this seemed to help, the frame being the name of your JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame` and `JApplet` are both [top-level containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). Instead of trying to have both containers present at once, put your content in a lightweight container such as `JPanel`; then add that `JPanel` to either a `JFrame` (for local use) or a `JApplet` (for the browser). This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) shows the approach.

Comment: I did try a JPanel as well but I'll take a look at your example, thanks.

Comment: See also [*What's Java Hybrid—Applet + Application?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12449889/230513).