# What's Java Hybrid - Applet + Application?

Tags: java, applet, desktop-application

And how can I write one?

From comments to my [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447764/166390), this followed:

> "What we had in the old days - An Applet and Application - is not available anymore."

And a rebuttal:

> Rubbish. It [An Applet and Application] is called an hybrid, and is alive and well. Ask on a separate question if you would like clarification.

I would like to ask **what this Java Hybrid is?**

I have searched but for some reason can't find any useful information for something that is "alive and well". The keywords I used maybe slightly off so that could be a reason.

Comment: I never heard that term, probably author's own.
IMO it's quite general and could be anything - e.g. Java + Java FX.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513).

Comment: How does that work? You have init and main in it, why no conflict? Where are the other life cycle methods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A *hybrid* applet/application simply abstracts the initialization of [two top-level containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), `JFrame` and `JApplet`. Examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513), [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) and [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/applet.html).

Addendum: *How does that work?*

- The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513) example exposes a factory method, `createGUI()`, and it adds the returned panel to the extant top-level container.
- The [second](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) provides a static `initContainer()` method, passing the enclosing top-level container as a parameter.
- The [third](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/applet.html) creates a [`class Hybrid`](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/hybrid.html) that has a static `fireup()` method and a `WindowListener` for error reporting.

Comment: +1  I was going to offer an answer, but this about covers it (far better than I would have).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was pretty much waiting for you. But since this covers it and the links do help. I will accept it thanks.

Comment: For convenient `appletviewer` testing, add the `<applet />` tag as a comment, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7455066/230513).

Answer (score 4):

A Java hybrid application is one that can be run as either an application or applet. The main application class is derived from either `java.awt.Applet` or `javax.swing.JApplet`.

As the `main` method is the entry point when running in application 'mode', it will not be called by the applet container.

The method

```
public void init()
```

is called automatically by the applet container but must be manually called from the `main` method (when running as an application).