# why doesn't InputMap method directly map keystroke objects to action objects?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, key-bindings

Why do we have to use the extra object `ActionMap`?
What's the meaning?

Take this as an example:

```
imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl Y"), "panel.yellow");

ActionMap amap = panel.getActionMap();

amap.put("panel.yellow", yellowAction);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13366367/230513), an `InputMap` associates a `KeyStroke` with an abstract *name* that identifies the correspoding `Action`. The `ActionMap` uses that name as a key to evoke a particular `Action` instance's `actionPerformed()` method. As a concrete example, this [`ScrollTimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7203419/230513) uses the `ActionMap` of a `JScrollPane` to look up actions by name and use them without direct access to the implementation.

Addendum: The abstraction was designed to support the ["pluggable look and feel"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) (L&F) architecture describe [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).