# how to add a Applet to a JPanel in java

Tags: java, swing, applet

Hi i am working on a  project and i stumbled along a problem where i cannot seem to add a Applet to a JPanel. People kept telling me that it is a component and i can just add it to the JPanel but it isnt displaying for me. I am having a lot of trouble with this and any help is appreciated :).

If you want here is the code (this code is example not my project):

```
 import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String artgs[]) throws Exception {
        String source = getPageSource(new URL(
                "http://www.runescape.com/game.ws?j=1"));
        Matcher matcher = SOURCE_PATTERN.matcher(source);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String first = matcher.group(1);
            String frameSource = getPageSource(new URL(first));
            matcher = ARCHIVE_PATTERN.matcher(frameSource);
            Matcher codeMatcher = CODE_PATTERN.matcher(frameSource);
            if (matcher.find() && codeMatcher.find()) {
                RSStub stub = new RSStub(PARAMETER_PATTERN, frameSource);
                URL world = new URL(first.substring(0, first.indexOf("/,")));
                stub.setCodeBase(world);
                stub.setDocumentBase(world);
                String archive = matcher.group(1);
                System.out.println(world.toString() + "/" + archive);
                Download(world.toString() + "/", archive);
                URLClassLoader clazzes = new URLClassLoader(
                        new URL[] { new URL("" + world.toString() + "/"
                                + archive) });
                Class<?> clazz = clazzes.loadClass("Rs2Applet");
                final Applet applet = (Applet) clazz.newInstance();
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                applet.setStub(stub);
                applet.init();
                applet.start();
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        applet.stop();
                        applet.destroy();
                        frame.dispose();
                        frame.setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(Color.black);
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension());
                panel.add(applet);
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getPageSource(URL url) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
        c.addRequestProperty(
                "Accept",
                "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"); // /By
                                                                                                                        // wyn10
        c.addRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        c.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        c.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5");
        c.addRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        c.addRequestProperty("Host", "www.runescape.com");
        c.addRequestProperty("Keep-Alive", "300");
        c.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
        DataInputStream di = new DataInputStream(c.getInputStream());
        byte[] tmp = new byte[c.getContentLength()];
        di.readFully(tmp);
        di.close();
        return new String(tmp);
    }

    public static void Download(String world, String archive) throws Exception {
        URLConnection jarConnection = new URL(world + archive).openConnection();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./gamepack.jar");
        InputStream input = jarConnection.getInputStream();
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            out.write(tmp, 0, read);
        }
    }

    public static final Pattern SOURCE_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("src=\"(.*)\" ");

    public static final Pattern ARCHIVE_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("archive=(.*) ");

    public static final Pattern CODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("code=(.*) ");

    public static final Pattern PARAMETER_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("<param name=\"([^\\s]+)\"\\s+value=\"([^>]*)\">");
}
```

### Stub

```
import java.applet.AppletContext;
import java.applet.AppletStub;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RSStub implements AppletStub {

    private URL documentBase;

    private URL codeBase;

    public void setDocumentBase(URL documentBase) {
        this.documentBase = documentBase;
    }

    public void setCodeBase(URL codeBase) {
        this.codeBase = codeBase;
    }

    public String[] keys = new String[2];

    private Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public RSStub(Pattern parameterPattern, String frameSource) {

        Matcher param = parameterPattern.matcher(frameSource);
        while (param.find()) {
            String key = param.group(1);
            String value = param.group(2);
            parameters.put(key, value);
            if (key.equals("0") || key.equals("-1")) {
                switch (key) {
                case "0":
                    keys[0] = key;
                case "-1":
                    keys[1] = key;
                }
                System.out.println("\t-> Client Deobfucation Key " + key
                        + " is " + value);
            }
        }
    }

    public String[] getDeobfucationKeys() {
        return keys;
    }

    public URL getDocumentBase() {
        return documentBase;
    }

    public URL getCodeBase() {
        return codeBase;
    }

    public String getParameter(String name) {
        return parameters.get(name);
    }

    public AppletContext getAppletContext() {
        return null;
    }

    public void appletResize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActive() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it has no sense. Applet is root container and should now have parent. (And try to use JApplet instead of Applet if you use swing. Do not mix swing with AWT.)

Comment: *"..cannot seem to add a Applet to a JPanel."*  Cannot seem to have the first idea of what is wrong given you don't describe: a) What you expected to happen. b) What actually happened.  As an aside, adding an applet to a panel is possible, but an extremely bad idea.  Do you control the applet code?

Comment: `panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension());`  That is certainly not helpful.  It would now have a preferred size of 0x0.

Comment: Why you want to add an Applet?

Answer (score 2):

Like `JFrame` and `JDialog`, `JApplet` is a Swing [top-level container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). You may be able to leverage the hybrid approach shown in the examples cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513).

Answer (score -1):

If the desired functionality is adding of an applet to your Panel, then you can do something like this :

```
getContentPane().add();
```

But first you must extend applet or jApplet.

This should work .