# MenuItem actionPerformed works in AppletViewer but not in Browser

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet, appletviewer

I am converting a medium-size (13892 LOC) Java Swing application into an applet.

So far, I've got the applet running and showing both in the Applet Viewer (via Eclipse) and showing in the browser (tested with Chrome and Firefox).

However, no click events are being registered by the application. Neither for JMenuItem, JButton, etc.

The general structure of the app is the following

```
public class MainWindow extends  JInternalFrame implements ActionListener { 
 ...
    private JToolBar toolBar;
    private JButton btnOpen;
 ...
    toolBar = new JToolBar();
    getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    btnOpen = new JButton("Open");
    btnOpen.addActionListener(this);
    toolBar.add(btnOpen);
 ...
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            btnOpen.setText("ACTION PERFORMED");
    if (event.getSource().equals(btnOpen)) {
        btnOpen_clicked();
    }       
    private void btnOpen_clicked() {
       btnOpen.setText(btnOpen.getText()+"/YAY!");
    }
}
```

Any clue on why would this happen?

Comment: *"I am converting a medium-size (13892 LOC) Java Swing application into an applet."* Easier for us & better experience for the end user is to simply launch the application using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Unfortunately, part of the migration consists on interacting with the container webpage (for example, replacing the console output).

Comment: What the..  Why is a Swing application putting anything to the *console?*  That will definitely need to be fixed before doing anything, and what advantage then remains for the applet form?

Comment: Perhaps a [_hybrid_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) would offer some flexibility? See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), required for both. `JInternalFrame` is usually used in a `JDesktopPane`.

Comment: It turns out it was a signing issue. The JAR file needed to be signed to get some needed permissions