# Wrapping An Applet Around An Application

Tags: java, swing

I have a working application, but I need to convert it to an applet. 
My main method isn't located in my frame class so I can't just extend `JApplet` and change my main method to `init()`. 
Is there an easy way to "wrap" an `applet` around an application.

Comment: pushing an applet around an application

Comment: Just initialize that (frame) class and make it visible in a new class which extends applet.

Comment: ok but if i make my main class extend japplet it creates and applet with nothing in it and then my usual frame...

Comment: i did that but it didn't work

Comment: If you need an applet, you need a class that extends JApplet or Applet, no workaround here I guess. You can make the frame visible in its constructor.

Comment: Yes I know I need a class that extends it, but can I have a class that just adds panels to applets?

Comment: You should be able to do that if you have access to an instance of the applet.

Comment: Several hybrid examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513); also consider [tag:javawebstart].

Answer (score 1):

I would separate out the guts of your UI creation, then call it either from main() or init().  See the below example:

```
public class Test extends Applet {
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    // run as application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.createUI();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(test.mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    // run as applet
    public void init() {
        createUI();
        add(mainPanel);
    }


    // create your UI here
    private void createUI() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(new JButton("Test"));
    }
}
```

Comment: So this somewhat worked, but now when I run the program it doesn't set the correct size, which really doesn't matter because when on a webpage it'll be the size I set in the HTML code.  The only problem is that when I go to export it through eclipse, it can't find a main class.  It finds a main class when I want to run it, but not when I try to export it.

Comment: @RiFFRaFF If you run it from Eclipse, it should automatically create a Run Configuration.  You should find this Run Configuration when you try to Export it, which is what points it to the main class.  Can't think of a reason why this wouldn't work.