# Why does applet initiate in default size before resizing to my specified size?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

Essentially the question says it all. I have a program where I initiate the canvas (`JApplet`) and set its size to not the default values. I wait for the timer to end and then it resizes. I don't want a delay, I aiming for instant.

How do I initiate the applet with a different size or background color on its first instance?

```
import javax.swing.JApplet; 
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class GameBoard extends JApplet {

    public void paint(Graphics canvas) {
        setSize(100,450);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //int 
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 2){
            waiting(1.0);
            i++;
        }
    }

public static void waiting (double n){
        long t0, t1;
        t0 =  System.currentTimeMillis();
        do{
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        while ((t1 - t0) < (n * 1000));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. DON'T call `setSize` inside `paint` EVER.  2. DON'T "pause" inside `paint` EVER - or for that fact, minimize all potential delays in the EDT full stop.  I though the `HTML` tag specified the preferred size of the applet, not the applet itself

Comment: Don't override the paint() method. You are not using a Timer. You are using a loop which is not the way to do animation. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) for the proper way to write an applet.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Your technical points are spot on, if a little.. enthusiastic. An applet does not have the luxury of setting its own size, it is a guest in the HTML that gives it whatever size is declared in the applet element.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, people screwing with `paint` just get me so <GRRR> :@

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I spent the better part of yesterday writing a script that includes my most sage comments.  Click each check box & the result is shown in a text area that I can copy/paste. It might get to stage where I'll select 1,6,9 & 11, make a comment then opt out till I get a notification or notice it in the daily round-up.  It was a very calming process..  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I just need a bot to do the same thing :P

Answer (score 1):

> How do I initiate the applet with a different size or background color on its first instance?

This is really two separate things, so I'll break it down.

1. Applet size
2. BG Color on load

### Applet Size

The applet size is set in HTML.  The applet viewer now supports parsing an applet element form the applet's source code file (that's right, the `.java` file), like this..

```
import javax.swing.*;

/* <applet code='HelloWorldApplet' width=400 height=100></applet> */
public class HelloWorldApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        add(new JLabel("Hello World!"));
        validate();
    }
}
```

### Applet BG color

See [Special attributes of applets: `boxbgcolor`, `boxfgcolor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#specialattributes)...

Comment: Also consider a [hybrid applet/application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) deployed via [tag:javawebstart].