# How swing java class to call applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

i have one Applet seperately without any main class,now i want to create one java main class(LIKE  LOGIN PAGE) from that i want to the call applet

**This is Applet main class i want call**

```
public class Appletmain extends Applet
{

    public Appletmain()
    {
        canvas = new Canvas(this);
        option = new Option(this);
        docu = new Docu(this);
        route = new Route();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        add("Center", canvas);
        add("North", docu);
        add("East", option);
        add("South", route);
    }

    public Insets insert()
    {
        return new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }

    public void lock()
    {
        canvas.lock(); 
        option.lock();
    }

    public void unlock()
    {
        canvas.unlock();
        option.unlock();
    }

    Canvas canvas;
    Option option;
    Docu docu;
    Route route;
}
```

**This my java main method**

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Appletmain b=new Appletmain();

    }
}
```

Comment: While it is possible to embed an applet in an app., it is not recommended.  It would be better to convert the applet code to panel code, then add the panel to whatever container (e.g. `JApplet`, `JFrame`, another `JPanel`, `JWindow`..) is needed.

Comment: Some examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12449889/230513).

Comment: how to convert applet code to panel code help me

Comment: Tip:  Add @trashgod (or whoever - the `@` is important) to notify a person of a new comment.  As to how to convert it, start looking over the examples linked in the 2nd comment, and if you fail, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best effort.