# How to update a JApplet GUI within a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, applet

I'm having problens in updating a JLabel inside a JApplet. I'm using SwingUtils.invokeLater but it doest not working when Applet is inside browser. When I test it on NetBeans Applet Viewer it works fine, but now in browser. It only updates when I first calls `sendMessage("Starting test 1");` but the others call to `sendMessage` doesnt not update GUI Applet. Any tips?

Here is the classe which execute some calculations:

```
public abstract class ConDiagnoseTool implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run(){
    String result = "";
    try {
        sendMessage("Starting test 1");
        result += execute();
        result += execute();
        sendMessage("Starting test 2");
        result += execute();
        sendMessage("Starting test 3");
        result += execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result += e.toString();
    }
    sendResult(result);
    sendMessage("Test finished.");
}

[...]

[...]

abstract void sendMessage(final String message);

abstract void sendResult(final String result);

}
```

And here I implement the abstract methods and call then whitin a GUI Thread:

```
private void btnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    new Thread(new ConDiagnoseTool() {
        @Override
        void sendMessage(final String message) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    jStatus.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        void sendResult(final String result) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    jResult.setText(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
    btnStart.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Thanks for reading it!

Comment: Works fine for me, got a working example..

Comment: Events are always fired on the `Event Dispatcher Thread`, so there is no need to use `invokeLater` inside `actionPerformed(...)` method.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, did you tested it on a browser? Because it works fine on Netbeans Applet Viewer has I already said.

Comment: @nIcEcOw So, why itsnt updating the GUI?

Comment: @nIcEcOw No, there not. Some events will be fired from the context that they were raised and in this example, setting the text of the labels will be done from the context of the thread which the call was made

Answer (score 2):

*All* Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). This applies to applications, applets and [hybrids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513). This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513) uses `SwingWorker` instead of a `Runnable`.

Comment: But i'm already doing that. No? Anyway the strange issue is that it updates fine on Netbeans Applet Viewer, but not in Browser.

Comment: No, absent an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), I don't see where you do that; different environments can expose the resulting race condition.