# How do I deploy my java application onto a website?

Tags: java, java-7, java-web-start, jnlp, japplet

I just complied all my java programs, which consists of 4 classes and everything's working fine. I have the GUI, client, server, and the action listeners and an image all in the same folder. I just don't know how to put my local java application that I debugged and tested in JGrasp software onto my webpage. I looked around and I read you need to make a jar file and compress all of them, but I don't know how to do that, neither creating an applet. I tried the most simple way of doing it by attempting to convert the .java file "SMTPServer", the class used to run the application, and convert that into a JNLP file and it brought up a Java WebStart Application, but was unable to run it. This is my first time trying to port it to the webpage. How do I do this?

Comment: what is the server you are using?

Comment: its all local. I tested it using 127.0.0.1

Comment: I mean did you use a local server like tomcat,jboss etc.

Answer (score 1):

This basic [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) is a [hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513). The JAR contains a single class. The JAR can be deployed as either an applet or application.  You can build a JAR containing your compiled class files in [`JGrasp`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jgrasp/info) as shown [here](http://webpages.sou.edu/~sahrk/cs200/executable.pdf).

```xml
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="YourApplication.jar"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Huh..  Why *not* use `lang-xml` for that XML snippet?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Good oil!

Comment: Very pretty.  :)  It can even help spot malformed HTML/JNLP/XML by sight.  I frequently use it for just that when editing questions. ;)