# Changing from Java Applet to JWS

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

I have an Applet that I would like to convert to a JWS file because of all this problem with compatibility with Chrome (and now, Edge). The problem is that I never used this technology so I would like some help.

Is there a step-by-step guide on doing this conversion? I mean, I have a class that extends java.applet.Applet implementing init and start, how do I change it to a JWS/JNPL class? And can it receive parameters like the applet?

We don't need it to run in the browser, so downloading and executing is fine. But it would be better if the browser executed it right away, instead of the user clicking on file downloaded. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Java Workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710181/google-chrome-java-workaround)

Comment: [Migration documentation from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/applet-migration-139512.html).

Comment: A complete example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19215601/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a step-by-step guide on doing this conversion?

The [JWS info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) here at SO has all the best JWS related links I could think to include.

> I mean, I have a class that extends java.applet.Applet implementing init and start, how do I change it to a JWS/JNPL class?

By Jarring the classes and digitally signing the Jars (if not already done) then writing a JNLP file to launch it (and possibly configuring the server to return the correct content-type for a JNLP file).

> And can it receive parameters like the applet?

Yes, they are specified in the JNLP file.