# Java JApplet to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, japplet

I want to convert a JApplet to a JFrame. I have found this code on the internet that is a word search game. I want to use this code in a demonstration for a class. but I don't want it in an applet. The code that I was going to paste in here was to large by about 7,000 characters. I tried taking the JApplet and extending a JFrame and then putting all of the code for the initialization into a constructor (Zero Argument constructor). This cause about ten errors that I couldn't get fixed. I want to make a word search game and I had found a great example but I cannot get it to run in my Eclipse.

```
class WordSearch extends JApplet
implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    // Copyright information.

    String copyName = "Word Search";
    String copyVers = "Version 1.1";
    String copyInfo = "Copyright 1999-2001 by Mike Hall";
    String copyLink = "http://www.brainjar.com";
    String copyText = copyName + '\n' + copyVers + '\n'
            + copyInfo + '\n' + copyLink;

    // Thread control variables.

    Thread loopThread;    // Main thread.

    // Constants

    static final int DELAY = 50;    // Milliseconds between screen updates.

    static final int INIT  =  1;    // Game states.
    static final int PLAY  =  2;
    static final int OVER  =  3;

    // Parameters and defaults.

    Color  scrnFgColor = Color.black;             // Background color.
    Color  scrnBgColor = Color.white;             // Foreground color.
    Color  scrnBdColor = Color.black;             // Border color.   
    String scrnFontStr = "Helvetica,bold,12";     // Font.

    Color  bttnFgColor = Color.black;             // Button background color.
    Color  bttnBgColor = Color.lightGray;         // Button foreground color.
    String bttnFontStr = "Dialog,bold,10";        // Button font.

    Color  gridFgColor = Color.black;             // Grid text color.
    Color  gridBgColor = Color.white;             // Grid background color.
    Color  gridHiColor = Color.yellow;            // Grid highlight color.
    Color  gridFdColor = Color.lightGray;         // Grid found color.
    String gridFontStr = "Courier,plain,14";      // Grid font.

    Color  listFgColor = Color.black;             // List text color.
    Color  listBgColor = Color.white;             // List background color.
    Color  listFdColor = Color.lightGray;         // List found color.
    String listFontStr = "Helvetica,plain,12";    // List font.

    int    gridRows    = 15;                      // Grid rows.
    int    gridCols    = 15;                      // Grid columns.
    int    gridSize    = 20;                      // Grid cell size.

    Vector files       = new Vector();            // List if text file URLs.

    // Global variables.

    static Vector words;    // Word list.

    Font scrnFont;    // Screen font.
    Font bttnFont;    // Screen font.
    Font gridFont;    // Grid font.
    Font listFont;    // List font.

    // Display elements.

    WSGrid   grid;
    WSList   list;
    WSButton newGame;
    WSButton solveGame;
    WSButton scrollUp;
    WSButton scrollDn;

    // File data.

    int fileNum;

    // Game data.

    int gap = 4;     // Gap between display elements.

    int    gameState;    // Game state.
    int    scroll;       // Scroll direction.
    int    count;        // Number of words found.
    long   startTime;    // Start time of current game.
    String timeText;     // Elapsed time text.
    String statText;     // Words found/total text.
    String subjText;     // Word list subject, from file.

    // Off screen image.

    Dimension offDimension;
    Image     offImage;
    Graphics  offGraphics;

    // Applet information.

    public String getAppletInfo() {

        return(copyText);
    }

    public void init() {

        Dimension d = getSize();
        Font f;
        FontMetrics fm;
        String s;
        StringTokenizer st;
        int n;
        Polygon p;
        int x, y;
        int w, h;

        // Display copyright information.

        System.out.println(copyText);

        // Set up mouse and key event handling and set focus to the applet window.

        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        requestFocus();

        // Get colors.

        s = getParameter("screencolors");
        if (s != null) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
            scrnFgColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
            scrnBgColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
            scrnBdColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
        }
        s = getParameter("buttoncolors");
        if (s != null) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
            bttnFgColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
            bttnBgColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
        }
        s = getParameter("gridcolors");
        if (s != null) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
            gridFgColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
            gridBgColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
            gridFdColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
            gridHiColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
        }
        s = getParameter("listcolors");
        if (s != null) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
            listFgColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
            listBgColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
            listFdColor = getColorParm(st.nextToken());
        }

        // Get fonts.

        scrnFont = getFontParm(scrnFontStr);
        s = getParameter("screenfont");
        if (s != null)
            if ((f = getFontParm(s)) != null)
                scrnFont = f;
        bttnFont = getFontParm(bttnFontStr);
        s = getParameter("buttonfont");
        if (s != null)
            if ((f = getFontParm(s)) != null)
                bttnFont = f;
        gridFont = getFontParm(gridFontStr);
        s = getParameter("gridfont");
        if (s != null)
            if ((f = getFontParm(s)) != null)
                gridFont = f;
        listFont = getFontParm(listFontStr);
        s = getParameter("listfont");
        if (s != null)
            if ((f = getFontParm(s)) != null)
                listFont = f;

        // Get grid size.

        s = getParameter("gridsize");
        if (s != null) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
            if ((n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())) > 0)
                gridRows = n;
            if ((n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())) > 0)
                gridCols = n;
            if ((n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())) > 0)
                gridSize = n;
        }

        // Get list of word file URLs.

        s = getParameter("files");
        if (s != null) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens())
                files.addElement(st.nextToken());
        }

        // Create and position letter grid.

        grid = new WSGrid(gridRows, gridCols, gridSize, gridFont);
        grid.setColors(gridFgColor, gridBgColor, scrnBdColor, gridFdColor,
                gridHiColor);
        grid.clear();

        // Create and position word list.

        fm = getFontMetrics(listFont);
        x = grid.x + grid.width + gap;
        w = d.width - x;
        h = grid.height - 2 * (fm.getHeight() + gap);
        list = new WSList(w, h, listFont);
        list.x = x;
        list.y = grid.y + fm.getHeight() + gap;
        list.setColors(listFgColor, listBgColor, scrnBdColor, listFdColor);

        // Create and position scroll buttons above and below work list.

        fm = getFontMetrics(bttnFont);
        w = list.width;
        h = fm.getHeight();
        p = new Polygon();
        p.addPoint(0, -h / 2 + 2);
        p.addPoint(-fm.getMaxAdvance() / 2, h / 2 - 2);
        p.addPoint(fm.getMaxAdvance() / 2, h / 2 - 2);
        scrollUp = new WSButton(p, w, h);
        scrollUp.x = list.x;
        scrollUp.y = grid.y;
        scrollUp.setColors(bttnFgColor, bttnBgColor, scrnBdColor);
        p = new Polygon();
        p.addPoint(0, h / 2 - 2);
        p.addPoint(-fm.getMaxAdvance() / 2, -h / 2 + 2);
        p.addPoint(fm.getMaxAdvance() / 2, -h / 2 + 2);
        scrollDn = new WSButton(p, w, h);
        scrollDn.x = list.x;
        scrollDn.y = list.y + list.height + gap;
        scrollDn.setColors(bttnFgColor, bttnBgColor, scrnBdColor);

        // Create and position text buttons under letter grid.

        fm = getFontMetrics(bttnFont);

        s = "New Game";
        w = fm.stringWidth(s) + fm.getMaxAdvance();
        h = 3 * fm.getHeight() / 2;
        newGame = new WSButton(s, bttnFont, w, h);
        newGame.setColors(bttnFgColor, bttnBgColor, scrnBdColor);

        s = "Solve Game";
        w = fm.stringWidth(s) + fm.getMaxAdvance();
        solveGame = new WSButton(s, bttnFont, w, h);
        solveGame.setColors(bttnFgColor, bttnBgColor, scrnBdColor);

        fm = getFontMetrics(scrnFont);
        x = (grid.width - (newGame.width + solveGame.width + gap)) / 2;
        y = grid.x + grid.height + fm.getHeight() + fm.getMaxDescent() + 2 * gap;
        newGame.x = x;
        newGame.y = y;
        solveGame.x = x + newGame.width + gap;
        solveGame.y = y;

        // Initialize game data.

        fileNum = 0;
        scroll = 0;
        timeText = "";
        statText = "";
        subjText = "";
        words = new Vector();
        grid.fill();
        endGame();
        gameState = INIT;
    }

    public Color getColorParm(String s) {

        int r, g, b;

        // Check if a pre-defined color is specified.

        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("black"))
            return(Color.black);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))
            return(Color.blue);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("cyan"))
            return(Color.cyan);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("darkGray"))
            return(Color.darkGray);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("gray"))
            return(Color.gray);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
            return(Color.green);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("lightGray"))
            return(Color.lightGray);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("magenta"))
            return(Color.magenta);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("orange"))
            return(Color.orange);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("pink"))
            return(Color.pink);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
            return(Color.red);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("white"))
            return(Color.white);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("yellow"))
            return(Color.yellow);

        // If the color is specified in HTML format, build it from the red, green
        // and blue values.

        if (s.length() == 7 && s.charAt(0) == '#') {
            r = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1,3),16);
            g = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3,5),16);
            b = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(5,7),16);
            return(new Color(r, g, b));
        }

        // If we can't figure it out, default to black.

        return(Color.black);
    }

    public Font getFontParm(String s) {

        String t, fontName;
        StringTokenizer st;
        int n, fontStyle, fontSize;

        fontName = "";
        fontStyle = -1;
        fontSize = -1;

        // Parse font name.

        st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
        t = st.nextToken();
        if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("Courier"))
            fontName = "Courier";
        else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("Dialog"))
            fontName = "Dialog";
        else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("Helvetica"))
            fontName = "Helvetica";
        else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("Symbol"))
            fontName = "Symbol";
        else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("TimesRoman"))
            fontName = "TimesRoman";

        // Parse font style.

        t = st.nextToken();
        if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("plain"))
            fontStyle = Font.PLAIN;
        else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("bold"))
            fontStyle = Font.BOLD;
        else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("italic"))
            fontStyle = Font.ITALIC;
        else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("boldItalic"))
            fontStyle = Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC;

        // Parse font size.

        t = st.nextToken();
        if ((n = Integer.parseInt(t)) > 0)
            fontSize = n;

        // Return the specified font.

        if (fontName != "" && fontStyle >= 0 && fontSize >= 0)
            return(new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize));

        // If we can't figure it out, return a null value.

        return (Font) null;
    }

    public void start() {

        if (loopThread == null) {
            loopThread = new Thread(this);
            loopThread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {

        if (loopThread != null) {
            loopThread.stop();
            loopThread = null;
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        long threadTime, elapsedTime;
        Date date;
        int m, s;
        String mm, ss;

        // Lower this thread's priority and get the current time.

        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        threadTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // This is the main loop.

        while (Thread.currentThread() == loopThread) {

            // Scroll word list.

            list.scroll += scroll;

            // Update game time.

            if (gameState == PLAY) {
                elapsedTime = threadTime - startTime;
                m = (int) (elapsedTime / 60000);
                s = (int) ((elapsedTime - 60000 * m) / 1000);
                mm = Integer.toString(m);
                ss = Integer.toString(s);
                if (mm.length() < 2)
                    mm = "0" + mm;
                if (ss.length() < 2)
                    ss = "0" + ss;
                timeText = "Time: " + mm + ":" + ss;
                statText = "Found: " + count + "/" + words.size();
            }

            // Update the screen and set the timer for the next loop.

            repaint();
            try {
                threadTime += DELAY;
                Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, threadTime - System.currentTimeMillis()));
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        // 'HOME' key: jump to web site (undocumented).

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_HOME)
            try {
                getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL(copyLink));
            }
        catch (Exception excp) {}
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        int x, y;

        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();

        // Check buttons.

        if (newGame.inside(x, y))
            initGame();
        if (gameState == PLAY && solveGame.inside(x, y))
            solveGame();
        if (gameState != INIT && scrollUp.inside(x, y))
            scroll = -1;
        if (gameState != INIT && scrollDn.inside(x, y))
            scroll = 1;

        // Check grid.

        if (gameState == PLAY && grid.inside(x, y)) {
            grid.select = true;
            grid.startX = x;
            grid.startY = y;
            grid.endX = x;
            grid.endY = y;
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        // Stop any scrolling.

        scroll = 0;

        // If a selection was being made, check it.

        if (gameState == PLAY && grid.select) {
            grid.select = false;
            if (grid.checkSelection())
                if (++count >= words.size()) {
                    timeText += " Done!";
                    statText = "Found: " + count + "/" + words.size();
                    endGame();
                }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        if (gameState == PLAY && grid.select) {
            grid.endX = e.getX();
            grid.endY = e.getY();
        }
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void initGame() {

        setWords();
        grid.select = false;
        grid.fill();
        list.scroll = 0;
        count = 0;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeText = "";
        statText = "";
        gameState = PLAY;
    }

    public void solveGame() {

        WSWord ws;
        int i;

        // Mark all words as found.

        for (i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            ws = (WSWord) words.elementAt(i);
            ws.found = true;
        }
        count = words.size();
        timeText = "Cheated!";
        endGame();
    }

    public void endGame() {

        gameState = OVER;
    }

    public void setWords() {

        String s;
        URL url;
        InputStream in;
        BufferedReader buf;

        // Clear word list.

        words.removeAllElements();

        // Get next file URL.

        if (fileNum >= files.size())
            fileNum = 0;
        s = (String) files.elementAt(fileNum);
        url = (URL) null;
        try {
            url = new URL(getDocumentBase(), s);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        fileNum++;

        // Open it up and read list of words.

        subjText = "";
        try {
            in = url.openStream();
            buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            while((s = buf.readLine()) != null)
                if (s.startsWith("#"))
                    subjText = "'" + s.substring(1) + "'";
                else if (s.length() > 0)
                    words.addElement(new WSWord(s));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {

        paint(g);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Dimension d = getSize();
        FontMetrics fm;
        String s;
        int x, y;
        int w, h;

        // Create the off screen graphics context, if no good one exists.

        if (offGraphics == null || d.width != offDimension.width || d.height != offDimension.height) {
            offDimension = new Dimension(d.width, d.height);
            offImage = createImage(d.width, d.height);
            offGraphics = offImage.getGraphics();
        }

        // Color the applet background.

        offGraphics.setColor(scrnBgColor);
        offGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);

        // Draw each game element.

        grid.draw(offGraphics);
        list.draw(offGraphics);
        scrollUp.draw(offGraphics);
        scrollDn.draw(offGraphics);
        newGame.draw(offGraphics);
        solveGame.draw(offGraphics);

        // Display title, messages, etc. as appropriate.

        offGraphics.setColor(scrnFgColor);
        offGraphics.setFont(scrnFont);
        fm = offGraphics.getFontMetrics();

        if (gameState == INIT) {
            x = (grid.x + grid.width) / 2;
            y = (grid.y + grid.height) / 2;
            w = Math.max(fm.stringWidth(copyName), fm.stringWidth(copyVers));
            w = Math.max(w, fm.stringWidth(copyInfo));
            w = Math.max(w, fm.stringWidth(copyLink));
            w += fm.getMaxAdvance();
            h = 6 * fm.getHeight();
            offGraphics.setColor(gridFgColor);
            offGraphics.fillRect(x - w / 2, y - h / 2, w, h);
            offGraphics.setColor(gridBgColor);
            offGraphics.drawRect(x - w / 2 + 1, y - h / 2 + 1, w - 3, h - 3);

            offGraphics.drawString(copyName, x - fm.stringWidth(copyName) / 2, y - 2 * fm.getHeight());
            offGraphics.drawString(copyVers, x - fm.stringWidth(copyVers) / 2, y -     fm.getHeight());
            offGraphics.drawString(copyInfo, x - fm.stringWidth(copyInfo) / 2, y +     fm.getHeight());
            offGraphics.drawString(copyLink, x - fm.stringWidth(copyLink) / 2, y + 2 * fm.getHeight());
        }

        x = (grid.x + grid.width - fm.stringWidth(subjText)) / 2;
        y = grid.y + grid.height + fm.getHeight();
        offGraphics.drawString(subjText, x, y);

        s = timeText;
        x = Math.min(d.width - fm.stringWidth(s), list.x);
        offGraphics.drawString(s, x, y);

        s = statText;
        x = Math.min(d.width - fm.stringWidth(s), list.x);
        y += fm.getHeight();
        offGraphics.drawString(s, x, y);

        // Copy the off screen buffer to the screen.

        g.drawImage(offImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}


These are the parameters that have to interact with the JApplet

<applet code="WordSearch.class" width=w height=h>
  <param name="screencolors" value="foreground,background,border">
  <param name="buttoncolors" value="foreground,background">
  <param name="gridcolors" value="foreground,background,found,highlight">
  <param name="listcolors" value="foreground,background,found">
  <param name="screenfont" value="name,style,size">
  <param name="buttonfont" value="name,style,size">
  <param name="gridfont" value="name,style,size">
  <param name="listfont" value="name,style,size">
  <param name="gridsize" value="rows,cols,size">
  <param name="files" value="url,url,url...">
</applet>
```

Comment: 1. Indeed extend (or create) `JFrame` as a main container. 2. Create `main` method that calls `init` method. If you still get errors - come back here.

Comment: You might be able to create a [hybrid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513).

Comment: An easier 'cheat' is to launch the applet (non-embedded) using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It will end up free-floating on the desk-top, wrapped in a frame.

Comment: I found were the java web start application is but I cannot find out how to get the java loaded into the application to run it. The instructions that I found said something about running from the command prompt but this I am not sure about. Do you have detailed instructions.  I can send you the .java if you want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following a very basic example...

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class MyWordGame extends JApplet {

    public void init(){
        add(new JButton("Test"));
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyWordGame game=new MyWordGame();
        JFrame myFrame=new JFrame("Test");
        myFrame.add(game);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        game.init();

    }

}
```

You can run it both as applet or application.
But remember that, if your applet interacts with browser, you must provide a custom AppletContext and you may also want to eventually provide a kind of management of applet's lifecycle (like calling start() / stop() / destroy() when appropriate).

Comment: Your example worked and it work really good. Is the game.init() have to be in there. I commented it out and I still could run as an applet. What makes it so that you can toggle between one or the other. Or is it just because the class extends the JApplet which is similar to that of a JPanel.

Comment: I tried to but more Jcomponents on and it would only show the last component. I added a BorderLayout() and it still didn't work. Can you show a bit more complete example if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Eclipse provides the "Run As Applet" option because your class extends Applet. When you run it as applet the main method doesn't get executed so commenting game.init() has no effect.

Comment: If you want to add more than one component to a BorderLayout you should specify the area you want to add your component to...
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new Button("South"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    p.add(new Button("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
If you add two components in the same area the second ovewrites the first. Default area is CENTER.

Comment: What if you have a FlowLayout() layout manager. This should allow me to add as many JComponents as possible to which ever form I am building them to.

Comment: When building an application is it wise to build it so that it would run both in a JApplet and a JFrame mode. Doesn't the JApplet just have an initialize method in it.

Comment: If you use a FlowLayout you can add as many components as you want and the LayoutManager will do its best to let them fit in the available space according to FlowLayout policy. Using BorderLayout you can only add five components in the five available areas: NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST, CENTER. Obviously any component you add might be a container and contain other components, so you can add more than five components using nested containers.

Comment: Consider what I gave you is a very basic example. As I said, in a real situation you must provide a way to manage applet's lifecycle. If you look at the code you posted there is a thread that you should start/stop calling start() and stop() methods according to applet lifecycle specification (i.e. calling start/stop when your frame becomes visible/invisible)... if you are not sure I suggest you google for applet lifecycle specification, it will clarify...

Comment: Sorry for the delay but was out of town. I will do the reading on this but quickly doesn't an JApplet have to have a run() method. If you were creating a GUI for JFrame and JApplet would it be best to make a GUI that is called in a method or the constructor so that both the JFrame and the JApplet would be able to use them.

Comment: 1. It can initialize itself.
2. It can start running.
3. It can stop running.
4. It can perform a final cleanup, in preparation for being unloaded. --::-- Here is what you mean on the life cycle.                     ---There is an init,start,stop, and destroy for the life cycle of an JApplet. Isn't the Start similar to the main method in a JFrame.

Comment: Well, I would say init method might be someway compared to a main. start/stop/destroy should probably be more related to JFrame visibility. I think I would consider having a WindowListener, associated to the JFrame, that performs start, stop and destroy on the applet reacting to Window events. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html

Comment: This JFrame trick is really handy when performance profiling in Netbeans since the main object hook is the context it has to run within to profile. This post is also quicker to get to  than previous incarnations of this trick on my own machine. Go figure.