# How to call an applet from another class's main method?

Tags: java, jar, applet

Bear with me as I am not well versed in how Applets work in java.
I have created a video game that runs in an applet, with other game object classes and image files in the package directory. I want to create an executable .jar to run the applet, but eclipse is asking for a launch configuration, so I assume I would need another class that deals with initializing the applet and anything else the applet might need.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Applets run in a web browser.

Comment: How would I go about putting the applet on a web browser?

Comment: How did you create your applet? Why did you choose Applets? Is [google](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html) broken?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different concepts:

1. A normal java program started by a main() method (it can be executed by calling a class, an executable jar, an exe file - there are lots of possibilities...)
2. A Java applet running in a web browser, managed by the java plugin of the web browser and subject to the [applet lifecycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html).

So basically you have to decide, what is important to you:

1. Do you want to run your game inside a webbrowser? (->  then write an applet)
2. Do you want a standalone application? (in form of class files, a runnable jar or exe)
3. Do you want to have both? There are also ways to do that:

   - If you implemented an applet, then you can also add a main() method and the necessary information to the [Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). Then when somebody starts your applet.jar your game is also started
   - There is a way to write an [draggable, offline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/draggableApplet.html) applet. Basically you can drag & drop your applet on your desktop and start it by double clicking it - even without internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Applets are Panels (see Applet class extends Panel) that provide a particular life-cycle so that you can attach them to the web-browser and the browser triggers life-cycle methods.
If you want to run an applet outside a web-browser you need to provide another "window" to attach it to and a way to trigger life-cycle's methods.

You can have a normal java Frame as "main window" and add the applet to it.
Then call applet's init method to start it.

For a more fine grained management of applet's life-cycle you'd probably want to write your own AppletContext.

See my answer here for a basic example (this one uses JApplet but the concept is the same for Applet): [Java JApplet to JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180650/java-japplet-to-jframe/20180873#20180873)

Hope it can help.