# JApplet not displaying data in a JTable correctly

Tags: java, swing, jtable, japplet

I have a applet program which reads data from an xml file and puts the elements in a list of movie objects. It then puts it in a JTable which has a custom table model to handle the data as well as a renderer to draw the title of the movie name into the table cells. I originally placed it in a JFrame and it worked perfectly as show in the image below.

[image]

However when I place it in a class which extends JApplet and call the getContentPane method it appears as this.

[image]

cells appear as "no programmes available" as the custom renderer writes it when the String movieName is "null".

Here is the applet code

```
public class BackEndApplet extends JApplet{

    private ArrayList<Channel> al;

    public void init() {

        setUp();

        try{
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    createGUI();
                }
                });

        } catch (Exception e){
             System.err.println("Did not run successfully");
        }

    }

    private void setUp(){
        //parse xml file into Java
        String fileName = "XMLFiles/bondFilms.xml";
        MovieParser movieParser = new MovieParser();
        movieParser.parseMovie(fileName);

        //sort movie list to channel and sort by time 
        MovieChannelSorter mcSorter = new MovieChannelSorter();
        mcSorter.sortMovieList(movieParser.getMovieList());

        //retrieves channels from channel sorter
        al = mcSorter.getChannels();
    }

    private void createGUI(){
        ProgrammeGuidePanel gPane = new ProgrammeGuidePanel(al);
        gPane.setOpaque(true);
        setContentPane(gPane);
    }  
}
```

and this my Main Panel code:

```
public class ProgrammeGuidePanel extends JPanel{


private ArrayList <Channel> channels;

private String [] channelNames =    {"Sean Connery",
                                    "George Lazenby",
                                    "Roger Moore",
                                    "Timothy Dalton",
                                    "Pierce Brosnan",
                                    "Daniel Craig"};

private String [] pHeader = {"Slot 1","Slot 2","Slot 3","Slot 4"};
private CustomTModel customModel;


public ProgrammeGuidePanel(ArrayList <Channel> ch) {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    channels = ch;

    //create title table    
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.addColumn("Channels",channelNames);
    JTable channelTable = new JTable(model);
    channelTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);                     

    //Create and fill Programme table
    customModel = new CustomTModel(channels,pHeader);
    JTable programmeTable = new JTable(customModel);


    //set up panel for titles
    JScrollPane scroller1 = new JScrollPane(channelTable);
    scroller1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,500));
    scroller1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,250));

    //set up panel for movies
    JScrollPane scroller2 = new JScrollPane(programmeTable);

    //scroller1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    //scroller1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,250)); 

    //add scrollPanes to main panel
    add(scroller1,BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(scroller2,BorderLayout.CENTER); 
}

}
```

I also tried using appletviewer in command line but it doesnt appear when i run the html file.

I'm completely stumped at why its doing it. So any help will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I may have figured out why its displaying the wrong data. In my Sax parser I was using

```
InputStream xmlInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
```

I tried creating an executable jar in eclipse and got the results of picture 2. So I assume my parser class was returning a list full of empty objects since it couldn'f find the xml file. I did some research and saw I had to use

```
InputStream xmlInput = getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.xml");
```

However it keeps returning null when I run it i eclipse. I've looked into some of the same questions in stackoverflow but I cant seem to get my head around on how to implement `getResourceAsStream()`. I've also used the `getClassLoader()` method and setting an absolute path with "/" but to no avail.

Here's an SSCCE of my parser.

```
public class XMLParser {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        XMLParser x = new XMLParser();
        x.parse();
    }

    public void parse(){

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

        try{
            InputStream xmlInput = getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.xml");
            //InputStream xmlInput = new FileInputStream("file.xml");  
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            saxParser.parse(xmlInput,handler);



            for(int i = 0;i<handler.plist.size();i++){
                System.out.println(handler.plist.get(i)); 
            }


        } catch (Throwable err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private class Handler extends DefaultHandler{

        ArrayList<String>plist = new ArrayList<String>();

        private String name;
        private String lastName;

        private boolean bname;
        private boolean blname;

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri,String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException{

            System.out.println("end element: " + qName);

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("NAME")) {
                bname = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LASTNAME")) {
                blname = true;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("end element: " + qName);

        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            if(bname){
                name = new String(ch,start,length);
                plist.add(name);
                bname = false;
            }

            if(blname){
                lastName = new String(ch,start,length);
                plist.add(lastName);
                blname = false;
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Here's what the structure looks like in Eclipse

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  MY best guess, based on the limited amount of information is that the applet is failing to load the data.  But then, I don't like guessing..

Comment: Make your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) a [hybrid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) for easy testing.

Comment: How is the data read?

Comment: I updated the question please take a look

Comment: Tip:  Add @trashgod (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify them* of a new comment.  BTW - an SSCCE is either an applet, a servlet/JSP, or has a `main(String[])`.  So while 'short', the `XMLParser` class is not (in itself) an SSCCE.  OK - why is that image down the bottom compacted?  It is almost unreadable. -- Do a `jar -tvf the.jar` and copy/paste the result as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20295985/edit).

Comment: @AndrewThompson is correct; see [tag:embedded-resource] and [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for examples and tutorials; try `jar tf` to see where `file.xml` ends up as built.