# Instantiate instance of JApplet in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, japplet

Right so my team mate has created a JApplet which contains a countdown

I have to take his `JApplet` and fit it inside a `JPanel/JTab` (Which its inside a `JFrame`), something from the NetBeans Palette.

Simply speaking i have a page with many components and I just want the countdown at the top right.

Using the GUI builder in netbeans, i created a `JPanel` and an event. In the event handler, i put:

```
private void jPanel1ComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO: Countdown

    Package.Packagename.Countdown.init();
}
```

The error message i get is:

non-static method init() cannot be referenced from a static context.

The Applet works fine on its own, i just cant put it in here.

Comment: _"I have to take his JApplet and fit it inside a JPanel"_ - Auto-Fail. `JApplet` is a top level container and should not be put inside of a `JPanel`. You _can_ however take the `JApplets` component contents and put _them_ inside the `JPanel`

Comment: Do you want another frame to open with the timer or did you want the timer embedded into the panel?

Answer (score 3):

> "I have to take his JApplet and fit it inside a JPanel"

`JApplet` is a top level container and should not be put inside of a `JPanel`. You can however take the `JApplets` component contents and put them inside the `JPanel`

**-OR-**

Instead of trying to use your friend's applet code, just create your own. Implementing a countdown is really not that difficult.  Just hand code it.

1. Drag and drop a label to the corner of your frame (`jLabel`)
2. Then use something like this

   ```
   public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
       int time = 100;

       public MyFrame () {
           initComponents();

           jLabel.setText(String.valueOf(count));

           javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swingTimer(1000, new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                   if (count == 0) {
                       ((javax.swing.Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                   } else {
                       count--;
                       jLabel.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                   }
               }
           });
           timer.start();
       }
   }
   ```

---

If you want, just make a `Timer` a class member that you can call from another `actionPerformed` to `start()` or `stop()` it

Comment: +1 for the [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) alternative; some hybrid examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513).

Answer (score 1):

An Applet is a web component that has nothing to do inside a desktop app.

Create a widget (something wrapped in a `JPanel` or whatever) that you will both use in your applet and your desktop app.

Comment: Im sorry could you expand on how you will do this? Inside NetBeans or Eclipse or something?

Comment: Well you need to put your "countdown component" classes into a separate "project". You will import the "countdown component" project from your two other projects (applet, desktop app) so you can re use the countdown component classes in both.

Comment: The solution I'm providing here is better explained by @peeskillet in the upper part of his answer.