# Simple JApplet Getting "NoClassDefFoundError" and don't know where it coming from

Tags: java, swing, noclassdeffounderror, japplet

I'm trying to make an sideshow program using Java applet, and everything is fine when I make and view the `JApplet` using eclipse but when I run the code in my browser I get `NoClassDefFoundError` which means there are some parts of my program that are undefined in `JApplet`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Applet extends JApplet {
    private int i = 0;
    private Button prev = new Button("prev");
    private Button next = new Button("next");

    public void init() {
        setSize(1100, 875);
        prev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (i == 0)
                    i = getList().length - 1;
                else
                    i--;
                repaint();
            }
        });

        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (i == getList().length - 1)
                    i = 0;
                else
                    i++;
                repaint();
            }
        });

        Panel buttons = new Panel();
        buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttons.add(prev);
        buttons.add(next);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add("South", buttons);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        setImg(g, getImgPath());
    }

    public String[] getList() {
        String[] str = { "./ (1).jpg", "./ (2).jpg", "./ (3).jpg","./ (4).jpg","./ (5).jpg","./ (6).jpg","./ (7).jpg","./ (8).jpg" };
        return str;
    }

    public String getImgPath() {
        return getList()[i];
    }

    public void setImg(Graphics g, String str) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), str);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
            g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My html code

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252" />

<body>
    <applet code=Applet.class width="200" height="200">
    </applet>
</body>

</html>
```

Screen shot:
[image]

Download everything:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0jqui0nomfb4zx/Code.zip

**My question is which part of my program is undefined for JApplet**

Thank you.

Comment: Please install java latest Plugin

Comment: latest plugin for what?

Comment: Did you click the Details button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol `$Applet$1` refers to an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), probably your applet's `ActionListener`. Your HTML needs to specify the location of the JAR containing *all* your classes, not just the enclosing class. Here are several things to consider:

- Make your applet a [*hybrid*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) for ease of development.
- Use [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start), as shown in the [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513), for ease of deployment.
- Don't use an existing superclass name, e.g. `Applet`, for your subclass.