# How can I create the following layout in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am new to Swing and I don't understand how to do layouts properly. I need to create the following layout

I have tried to use a grid layout and a border layout but I just can't get it to look the way I designed it in the picture. Can anyone help me?

[image]

**Attempt**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Test extends JFrame
{
    public Test()
    {

        //Make a content frame
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        Container contentPane2 = getContentPane();
        Container contentPane3 = getContentPane();

        //Create a grid layout - This will go to the left
        contentPane.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 4, 1 ) );  //4 Rows and 1 Columns
            //Button 1
            contentPane.add ( new JButton ( "Button 1" ) );
            //Button 2
            contentPane.add ( new JButton ( "Button 2" ) );
            //Button 3
            contentPane.add ( new JButton ( "Button 3" ) );
            //Button 4
            contentPane.add ( new JButton ( "Button 4" ) );

        //Create a border layout - This will go in the middle.
        contentPane2.setLayout ( new BorderLayout() );
            //Label - Welcome to my application
            contentPane2.add ( new JLabel ( "Welcome to my application" ) );
            //Image 1
            contentPane2.add  ( new ImageIcon("img/button.png" ) );
            //Change background colour

        //Create a grid layout - This will go to the right
        contentPane3.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 4, 1 ) ); //4 Rows and 1 Columns
            //Button 5
            contentPane3.add ( new JButton ( "Button 5" ) );
            //Button 6
            contentPane3.add ( new JButton ( "Button 6" ) );
            //Button 7
            contentPane3.add ( new JButton ( "Button 7" ) );
            //Button 8
            contentPane3.add ( new JButton ( "Button 8" ) );


        //Set window parameters
        setTitle ( "Test Application" );
        setSize ( 200, 200 );
        setVisible ( true );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {

        Test myFrame = new Test();

    }//End main


}//End Class
```

Comment: Post your best attempt.

Comment: @ JB Nizet okay here is my attempt, to be honest I have noooo idea what I am doing ;(

Comment: Then you shouldn't ask a question. Instead, you should read documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html. Note that you can use several layouts. For example, use a grid layout for a panel containing the first 4 buttons, same for the last 4 buttons, and a border layout for the two button panels and for the image on the center.

Comment: JB Nizet I already have, I can create those basic layouts but I cannot create the layout I want.

Comment: What you posted shows that you haven't: you're using a single grid layout, and if you had read the documentation correctly, you would realize immediately that it can't possibly work. Read the documentation again, carefully, and read my previous comment.

Comment: @JB Nizet I only gave you my attempt at a grid layout not a border layout, I did not know you could use both together.

Comment: *"I did not know you could use both together."* Combining layouts is something that I do **not** think is well explained in the tutorial. See this example of [combinations of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for some tips. Also have a look at using layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556), for a less 'crowded' GUI as seen in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read comments :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Test extends JFrame{

    //when posting code make resources available
    URL url = new URL("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg");

    public Test() throws IOException  {

        //You clearly have three different areas in your design, so start by making:
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        JPanel right = new JPanel();

        //left and right panels holds 4 buttons each. GridLayout will make
        //them occupy equal space. You could also use other layout managers like
        //Box
        left.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 4, 1 ) );  //4 Rows and 1 Columns
        //Button 1
        left.add ( new JButton ( "Button 1" ) );
        //Button 2
        left.add ( new JButton ( "Button 2" ) );
        //Button 3
        left.add ( new JButton ( "Button 3" ) );
        //Button 4
        left.add ( new JButton ( "Button 4" ) );

        //Create a border layout - This will go in the middle.
        center.setLayout ( new BorderLayout() );
        //Label - Welcome to my application
        center.add ( new JLabel ( "Welcome to my application"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //Image 1
        ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(url));
        center.add ( new JLabel(icon), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Create a grid layout - This will go to the right
        right.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 4, 1 ) ); //4 Rows and 1 Columns
        //Button 5
        right.add ( new JButton ( "Button 5" ) );
        //Button 6
        right.add ( new JButton ( "Button 6" ) );
        //Button 7
        right.add ( new JButton ( "Button 7" ) );
        //Button 8
        right.add ( new JButton ( "Button 8" ) );

        //add JPanel to content pane which uses Borderlayout by default
        getContentPane().add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        getContentPane().add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);

        //Set window parameters
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle ( "Test Application" );
        //setSize ( 200, 200 ); //size set by layout
        pack();
        setVisible ( true );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException   {
        new Test();
    }//End main
}//End Class
```

Comment: Sorry for such a basic question, I see you use Jpanel() and I am using container(), what is the difference between the two?

Comment: `JPanel` is a subclass of `Container` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030636/what-is-the-difference-between-container-and-panel (Actually you use one container. All your containers `= getContentPane();`)

Comment: That worked fine for me, I made some changes to the code to load a local image file and just changed a few items, I am trying to find a GUI builder that might help me learn this a little better. Thanks for the help.

Comment: *"I am trying to find a GUI builder that might help me learn this a little better."* To use a GUI builder properly, you first need to understand how to create the GUI using plain old Java code. A GUI builder won't either teach, or help, to understand that.

Comment: Netbeans has a good swing GUI builder. Better use manual coding to learn, as @AndrewThompson suggested.