# Converting a java application to a JApplet in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, japplet

I have created a java application that is supposed to work as a flight editor. I have a database and  a total of 9 classes. Every class extends JFrame and is a separate form for each of the classes. So basically when you press a different button from the main frame it redirects you to another frame depending on the button you have pressed. I am doing this in NetBeans 7.4 and I want to convert it into an JApplet so that I can make it a web-application after finishing with the conversion. I have searched on the internet for guides on how to do that but the ones that could work for me are not up-to-date with the current NetBeans changes. If there is an easier way than what I have in mind feel free to say it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`total of 9 classes. Every class extends JFrame and is a separate form for each of the classes.`

don't to create bunch of `JFrame`s use

1. `CardLayout` with `JFrame.pack()` after card is switched
2. remove a) `JPanel` contains `JComponent`, b) add another `JPanel` contains `JComponent`, c) call `JFrame.(re)validate`, `JFrame.repaint()`, then `JFrame.pack()` as last code lines, after all changes to already visible GUI is done

> and I want to convert it into an JApplet so that I can make it a
>   web-application after finishing with the conversion.

1. `Java Web Start`
2. `JavaFX` container with `Swing JComponent`s (`JPanel`s by using `CardLayout`)
3. pure `JavaFx application`

Comment: Also consider crating a [hybrid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) for convenience during development and possible refactoring.