# Cannot get website applet to work with Java 8 u20

Tags: java, security, applet

Not sure if this is the best place to post this, but I always get good answers from you guys/girls, so here goes:

I'm working with a .jar applet on a website, and after finally getting it to work, Java tells me my security settings are blocking it. The most recent java update (8 u20) has removed the medium > high > very high slider for security settings, and all that's left is High and Very High. I attempted to put the website on the exception site list, but I still get a security error. Is there any way I can get my applet working on the site? I've done research but the update is very recent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider a [hybrid](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12449889/230513) with [tag:java-web-start].

Comment: I've been looking for quite a while, and I can't seem to understand how to adapt my applet for Java Web Start. I see you need some type of JNLP file as well as well as applet-desc codes , and attempts to get it up and running have been futile. I'm pretty lost. How do I use these applet-desc tags and why are they necessary?

Comment: Several examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513).

Comment: Digitally sign the applet.  That is the only course of action likely to allow the applet to be loaded.