# Alternative way to launch webstart after Chrome drops NPAPI?

Tags: java, google-chrome, java-web-start

I have a webstart application that I was launching via my website using the Oracle deployment tools

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/createWebStartLaunchButtonFunction.html

But after Chrome dropped support for NPAPI I can no longer use this as Chrome now blocks this.  What are some recommended alternative methods for launching a webstart application that is Chrome compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A link to the `.jnlp` file itself continues to work in [version 47.0 of Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_release_history). This [`AlphaCompositeDemo`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) is an example. The user may then choose to open the file with [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) or save the file to disk for later installation. If your application is actually an applet, consider creating a [hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12449889/230513).

See also [*How will Java be supported in Chrome after Chrome drops the NPAPI support?*](https://www.quora.com/How-will-Java-be-supported-in-Chrome-after-Chrome-drops-the-NPAPI-support)

Comment: I think is not working jnlp file is blocked by Java Security after downloaded. And yes you can add a exception to the exception list, but blew ... this seems to messy for final users

Comment: @DiegoQuirós: Messy, but it keeps the user in control; in the example cited, you can simply build form source.